# 'nx' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: nrwl-nx

I am trying to add a new util library into my Nx mono repo. I googled and found the following command from `www.nx.dev`:

```
nx generate @nrwl/nest:library util/util-myLibName
```

When I run the above command, then I get the following message:

> The term 'nx' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
> script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
> if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and  try
> again.

I searched the web a lot, but couldn't find the solution.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is because the nx don't installed in your s.o

Try first

> npm install -g @nrwl/cli

Comment: I used `yarn global add "@nrwl/cli` and worked.

Answer (score 35):

Tried the below command on Windows and it worked:

```
npm install -g nx
```

https://nx.dev/getting-started/nx-setup

Answer (score 9):

Instead of:
`nx serve`

Do:
`npx nx serve`

because **npx** is a package runner that can execute any package that you want from the npm registry without even installing that package.

Otherwise you can install nx package by using the following command:

`npm install --location=global nx`

Answer (score 7):

try

```
npx nx generate @nrwl/nest:library util/util-myLibName
```

Answer (score 3):

I ended up running from the local package file:

`./node_modules/.bin/nx`

Migration example:
`./node_modules/.bin/nx migrate latest`

I did this because installing @nrwl/cli globally did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to install `npm install -g @nrwl/cli` and this will fix all.

Happy Coding !!!